# trying to convert calc app to typescript, what type is this function suppose to be?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

- I'm trying to convert this calculator app into TypeScript.
- the three functions, (handleClick, handleEqual, handleClear) how come typescript is NOT yelling at me to specify something about the type of their functions? Only one takes an argument, which is a number, is I specified the type of the argument for val:number. But is that really all I need here?
- Is there a site that you recommend that can help figure types out? Seems quite confusing.

  ```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import * as math from 'mathjs';
    import '../styling/App.css';
    import { Button } from './button';
    import { Input } from './input'
    import { ClearButton } from './clear-button';

    const App = () => {
      const [input, setInput] = useState('');

      const handleClick = (val: number) => {
        setInput(input + val)
      }

      const handleEqual = () => {
        setInput(math.evaluate(input))
      }

      const handleClear = () => {
        setInput('');
      }

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="calc-wrapper">
            <Input input={input}/>
            <div className="row">
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>7</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>8</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>9</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>/</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>4</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>5</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>6</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>*</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>1</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>2</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>3</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>+</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>.</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>0</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleEqual}>=</Button>
              <Button handleClick={handleClick}>+</Button>
            </div>
            <ClearButton handleClear={handleClear} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
  ```

I've now edited to add my button component

```
    import React, {FC} from 'react';
    import '../styling/button.css';

    // create types for props
    type ButtonProps = {
      // HandleClick needs to a be a function type with a parameter that takes a ReactNode (since that's the type of props.children in this case, and you want to pass it into that function
      handleClick: (children: React.ReactNode) => void; // basically, clicking the reusable component I made, the arg is a ReactNode 
      // don't need to specify children prop, <ButtonProps> has it by default
    }

                    // set type for value
    const isOperator = (val: React.ReactNode) => {
      // isNaN() only takes a number parm, and only checks whether a number is set to specal value of 'NaN'
      return (typeof val === "number" && !isNaN(val)) || val === "." || val === "=";
    }

    // generic type, FC
    export const Button: FC <ButtonProps> = ({children, handleClick}) => {
      return (
        <div className={`button-wrapper ${isOperator(children) ? null : "operator"}`}
            onClick={() => handleClick(children)}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Typescript would complain if you tried to use `e` in a callback without typing the arguments, but you aren't using any arguments here.  It is unusual for a `handleClick` to be used multiple times like this, but it's all down to what your `Button` component does with it.  If `Button` is setting an `onClick` that calls `props.handleClick(props.children)` then that will work.  Actually, you have non-numeric buttons being using `handleClick` so you need it to take `(val: string)`.  That error would show up in your `Button` file, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is really all you need *in this component*.  Typescpript is able to infer a lot base on usage.  For example, you don't need to declare that you `input` state is a `string` because it assumes this based on the type of the initial value `""`.

There *are* problems with the typescript types in this code, but they are going to be showing up on your `Button` component.  `Button` is receiving a `handleClick` function that takes a `number` as its argument.  Is that ok?  How do you handle a click on the `*` button?  How are you calling a function which can only take a `number`?

If our button does accept the props exactly as we are providing them, then it would look something like this:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  handleClick: (val: number) => void;
  children: ReactNode; // this is the default so it's not actually needed here
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ handleClick, children }) => (
  <button onClick={() => handleClick(children)}>{children}</button>
);
```

We will get an error when calling `handleClick(children)`:

> Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

Ok, so we can't allow just any `children`.  If we add `{children: number;}` to `ButtonProps` then that fixes the error in `Button` but creates a new error in `App`:

> 'Button' components don't accept text as child elements.

So we need to read the `children` prop as a `string`.  Our `Button` will look like this:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  handleClick: (val: string) => void;
  children: string;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ handleClick, children }) => (
  <button onClick={() => handleClick(children)}>{children}</button>
);
```

Now we get a different error in App:

> Type '(val: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(val: string) => void'

Which brings us full circle.  We just change the type of the `handleClick` function and we're done!

```
const handleClick = (val: string) => {
  setInput(input + val);
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-calculator-pe69s?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: thank you, this is detailed and helpful. couple questions to help me understand.... first, I added/edited so you can see the button.tsx file. second, currently, my handleClick function takes children in as an argument because the user clicks on the (number or string) which is a reusable component. You think I should still change it to just 'string' type?

Comment: In your current code you should have an error in `App` on every `handleClick` property: `Type '(val: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(children: ReactNode) => void` so you would need to change your handler to `const handleClick = (val: React.ReactNode) =>`.  That does work.  `setInput(input + val)` doesn't give you any errors because it will can always cast `val` to a string no matter what it is.  The children in your app are only `string` so it works fine here but you could have some strange behaviors if the children are different.

Comment: If you put a `Button` inside a `Button` you don't get any TS warnings or errors, but when you click on it your `input` becomes `[object Object]` (because `children` is a React element `object` which gets cast to a `string`).  Regarding numbers, when you set the children automatically through JSX it's always a `string` `"7"`.  In order to get it as a `number` you would have to pass it as a variable.  Either with curly braces `<Button handleClick={handleClick}>{7}</Button>` or setting it as a prop `<Button handleClick={handleClick} children={7}/>`.

Comment: So I think `string` or `string | number` is better than `ReactNode` because it provides you with maximum type safety and prevents you from using it in a way that will cause problems, like the nested buttons situation described earlier.  You want to restrict the `children` prop of the button so that it's only something that you can handle.